# React-native Flatlist Data Post into Api

Tags: android, react-native

I want to post my Flatlist data row by row . Here is the image the data I get [image]

Here I fetch Data from a api and this is my view code for flatlist data load

```
 this.state = {
  data: [],
  //data_local: data_local,
  radio_props: radio_props,
  animating: true
  //test_data:test_data,
};

<FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "row",
            height: 50,

            backgroundColor: "#D1F2EB",
            borderRadius: 4,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "#008000",
            marginLeft: "1%"
          }}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              flex: 2,
              fontSize: 19,
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              width: 150
            }}
          >
            {item.rollno}--{item.name}
          </Text>

          <RadioForm
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              flexDirection: "row",
              padding: 10,
              width: 30
            }}
            radio_props={radio_props}
            initial={0}
            onPress={value => {
              this.setState({ value: value });
            }}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          />
        </View>
      )}
      // keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}

      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />

    <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => this.insert()} />
  </View>
```

Now I want to post all this flatlist data . Please note that I can post only one data and that is static. How can I post all of these data row by row.
Here Is my code that is posting only one data

```
insert = () => {
/* */
//alert(this.state.username);
fetch("http://192.168.1.139:8082/Attendence/add", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "rollno": "1170",
    "typeofattendence": 0
  })
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(res => {
    if (res.success === true) {
      alert(res.message);
    } else {
      alert(res.message);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
   };
```

Please help me.Thanks

Comment: Create an endpoint that supports receiving multiple items, instead of just one.

Comment: First I want to insert first  row then I will insert multiple can you give me the code of first row insert or post

Comment: make a button with row and call a function for post data . data can be pass as paramter... its simple

Comment: can you give me some code sample I'm new in React native